# copy categories from other categories in same magento

Tags: php, category, magento1.9.2.3

I want to copy categories with sub categories and add it to another categories with same mangento with different stores.

For Example:

```
Store One Category
      Category 1
         Sub Category 1
         Sub Category 2
      Category 2
         Sub Category 1
         Sub Category 2

Store Two Category
```

Now from this I want to add all Categories of **Store One Category** to **Store Two Category** without any extention.

Comment: Personally i am using extension for that and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: if you don't want an extension how do you expect to do it?

Comment: It can be possible using code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I got solve for this question.

```
<?php
    require_once 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();
    $categories  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('id')->getChildrenCategories(); //here id of category which you want to copy categories.

    $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('id'); //here id of category which you want to paste categories.
    foreach ($categories as $category) 
    {
        echo $category->getId()."<br>";
        $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());

        $copy = clone $category;
        $copy->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
        $copy->getProductCollection($prodCollection);
        $copy->setId(null) 
         ->save();

        foreach ($collection as $product) 
        {
           $product->getId();
           $cate = $product->getCategoryIds();
           $cate[] = $parentCategory->getId();
           $cate[] = $copy->getId();
           $product->setCategoryIds($cate);
           $product->save();
        }
        echo $copy->getId()."<br>";
    }
?>
```